# Alternative to https://safe-relay.gnosis.io/api/v3/safes/estimates/?

Tags: gnosis-safe

From my understanding, `https://safe-relay.gnosis.io` has been deprecated. In the past, I used `https://safe-relay.gnosis.io/api/v3/safes/estimates/` to get gas estimates for safe creation.

Is there another API?

Answer (score 0):

Figured this out by looking into the `safe-core-sdk`

```typescript
import { SafeAccountConfig, SafeFactory } from '@gnosis.pm/safe-core-sdk'
import {
  EthAdapter,
  TransactionOptions
} from '@gnosis.pm/safe-core-sdk-types'

import { SAFE_LAST_VERSION } from '@gnosis.pm/safe-core-sdk/dist/src/contracts/config'
import { getProxyFactoryContract, getSafeContract } from '@gnosis.pm/safe-core-sdk/dist/src/contracts/safeDeploymentContracts'
import { EMPTY_DATA, ZERO_ADDRESS } from '@gnosis.pm/safe-core-sdk/dist/src/utils/constants'

// Estimate GnosisSafe Wallet Creation Gas

export async function estimateGasForWalletCreation(
  ethAdapter: EthAdapter,
  signerAddress: string,
  chainId: number,
  owners: string[],
  threshold: number
): Promise<number> {
  const safeVersion = SAFE_LAST_VERSION
  const isL1SafeMasterCopy = false

  const safeProxyFactoryContract = await getProxyFactoryContract({
    ethAdapter,
    safeVersion,
    chainId
  })
  const gnosisSafeContract = await getSafeContract({
    ethAdapter,
    safeVersion,
    chainId,
    isL1SafeMasterCopy
  })

  const initializer = gnosisSafeContract.encode('setup', [
    owners,
    threshold,
    ZERO_ADDRESS,
    EMPTY_DATA,
    ZERO_ADDRESS,
    ZERO_ADDRESS,
    0,
    ZERO_ADDRESS
  ])

  const saltNonce = (Date.now() * 1000 + Math.floor(Math.random() * 1000)).toString()
  const safeMasterCopyAddress = gnosisSafeContract.getAddress()
  const gas = await safeProxyFactoryContract.estimateGas(
    'createProxyWithNonce',
    [
      safeMasterCopyAddress,
      initializer,
      saltNonce
    ],
    {}
  )

  return gas
}
```